# Is there a way to reason your way to figuring out what expressions use the subjunctive or are the reasons merely after-the-fact justifications?

Tags: subjonctif

On websites like Lawless French you'll find big lists of expressions that require the subjunctive, under headings like preferences, emotions, advice, order, doubt, supposition, possibilities, etc. For instance, être triste que, il est temps que, and refuser que.

Then there are other expressions, such as use of the verb croire or penser, that apparently take the subjunctive only in certain cases (when negative or in question form), like: Croit-elle que ce soit assez dire ?

Anyhow, is this really a matter of memorizing dozens of expressions through repeated use or is there a logic to it (e.g., degree of uncertainty or doubt expressed) that can be applied to any verb or expression and tell you whether the subjunctive is required?

For instance, the website French Today has this to say:

> So, between 100% chance (indicative) and 0% chance (subjunctive), what
> mood should you use? Where do you draw the line?
>
> - If you know for sure it’s the reality = Indicative in French.
> - Over 70% chance of the action becoming a reality = Indicative in    French.
> - If there is under 70% chance of the action becoming a reality =     Subjunctive in French.

Comment: The *rules of thumb* are already given in your question. If you are looking for a strict mathematical rule that works 100% of the time then no, such does not exist - languages are full of idiosyncratic features.

Comment: No, the 100% that's not what I was looking for, but more of additional rules or confirmation of the rules I already posed. Particularly the idea that subjunctif is subjective, so that people couldn't criticize my lack of use if "I believe" certain thing to be true or likely true, which, as the above notes, would require the indicative.

Comment: A French joke attributed to Émile Zola : *Dans la vie, il y a deux types de personnes, ceux qui sachent et ceux qui croivent sachoir.*

Comment: haha, wonderful, thanks for sharing.